# Integers less than $7000$ achievable by starting with $x=0$ and applying $x\to\lceil x^2/2\rceil$, $x\to\lfloor x/3\rfloor$, $x\to9x+2$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, functions, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

### Problem

Robert is playing a game with numbers. If he has the number $x$, then in the next move, he can do one of the following:

- Replace $x$ by $\lceil{\frac{x^2}{2}}\rceil$
- Replace $x$ by $\lfloor{\frac{x}{3}}\rfloor$
- Replace $x$ by $9x+2$

He starts with the number $0$. How many integers less than or equal to $7000$ can he achieve using the above functions?

*[It is permitted to use a number greater than $7000$ in the way of achieving the desired numbers.]*

### My Approach

Call the functions $f_1,f_2,f_3$ respectively. $2$ is easily achievable from $0$ (using $f_3$). I've found that all the integers from $0$ to $10$ are achievable (Though we achieve them in a long way). The numbers get messy when we get ahead further. I can't prove that any number is unachievable. I've noticed that base-$3$ numbers can help for $f_2$ and $f_3$.

---

How to get ahead further?

**Update:** Mr. Mike showed that all integers are *achievable* by this process through codes. Mr. Calvin also gave a partial proof for that. So, a complete proof is needed currently.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: This is from an Olympiad training camp. I don't have the link of the problem though @Misha

Comment: Why don't you show how you got 0-10?  It could be useful for reaching larger numbers.

Comment: I believe that you're on the right track. A) I encourage you to verbalize why working in base 3 is helpful.  B) I think that to reach $n$, we reach a number that is bounded between $ n \times 3^k$ and $ (n+1) \times 3^{k}$.

Comment: That would be a long process. Numbers from 0 to 400 need to be examined for that @RaviFernando

Comment: @FNishat conjecture: you probably don't need $f_3$ at all for $n\geq 3$; my not-entirely-random speculation is that starting from $n=3$ all numbers are generated by $f_1$ and $f_2$ alone.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki [This code confirms your conjecture is true.](https://tio.run/##XU/LTsMwEDzjr9hb7WI5r0pIVXvgE3IuEXLbTRMpsc3GgSLEt4c4NUJlTt6dh3fcp2@sKaapJttDg9q9Qds7S34Z3Dg08vayjjGv6YJ@gD0M6Dlpc0G@kfCUppkQjA2IJnKHVGYyl0UlWDmvDkXF2EfTdggxY8tgxmkkQuNnRfyDl2IhvH3V53NwRkmSFBJ4HNbrHB4hE0mSV4u8tgRXaE303cID2nreG@sDF877YwJ@K/JSwlXcUUGs5ij@b78E7vahc3of9hCbKcLevmMwMket8Xz1Yp67DszYH5GGcMpXJpVSMoR8gyYEQn1q9LFDtRLT9AM "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think you mean for $n>3$? From $\{0,1,2\}$ you don't get anything new with just $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: @Servaes No, I mean $\geq 3$; from ${3}$ you get $5$ by applying $\lceil x^2/2\rceil$, $13$ by applying it again, and then $4$ by applying $\lfloor x/3\rfloor$; etc etc.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I seem to be misunderstanding; how do you get $n=3$ from $\{0,1,2\}$ with $f_1$ and $f_2$ alone?

Comment: @Servaes Ahhh! Yes, what I was trying to say was that it seems likely that starting with any $n\geq 3$ you can get all other $n$ by application of just $f_1$ and $f_2$; that $f_3$ is _only_ needed to get out of the 'pit' of $\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ah I understand what you meant now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is not a valid solution.
Ravi pointed out that there is an error.

---

**Claim:** For any integer $n$, there exists integers $K , L \geq 0$ such that $$  n\times 3^K \leq 2 \times 10 ^{2^L} \leq (n+1) \times 3^K.$$

**Proof:** Working mod $\log 3$, we want to show that there exists a $L > 0$ such that

$$ \frac{\log n - \log 2}{\log 10} \leq  2^L \leq \frac{\log (n+1) - \log 2}{\log 10} \quad \pmod{ \log 3}$$

(I am unable to complete this proof. It requires us to show that $\frac{1}{ \log 3} $ in base 2 has all finite binary strings.)

**Corollary:**  $ b^K a^{L-1} c^2 (0) = n$, where

- $a(x) = \lceil \frac{ x^2 }{ 2 } \rceil $
- $b(x) = \lfloor \frac{x}{3} \rfloor $
- $c(x) = 9x+2$.

---

Notes

- As conjectured and established via computer by Steven and Mike respectively, after using $ c(0) = 2, c(2) = 20$, it seems like we don't need the $c(x)$ function anymore.
- In addition, since $ab(x) \approx b^2a(x) \approx \frac{x^2}{18}$ (but the floor and ceiling functions could get in the way of equality), if there was a sequence to get to $n$ using just $a(x), b(x)$, then it might be reasonable that we could collate $a(x), b(x)$ separately.
- The above 2 comments could motivate the given solution. However, that's not how I came up with it.
- Working in base 3 is suggested by functions $b(x), c(x)$, and $bbc(x) = x$.
- (for me at least)  Viewing $b(x)$ as truncating in base 3 and $c(x)$ as appending 02 in base 3, made it much easier to think about these function.
- Based on initial iterations (esp because I avoided $a(x)$ as that made numbers huge), my guesses for achievable numbers were  like A) $6k, 6k+2$, B) $2k$, C) Trenary numbers involving only 0 and 2 (maybe with additional conditions).
- It is clear that if we only used $b(x), c(x)$, then the base 3 representations are limited to digits of 0 and 2 (and in fact, 2's must be separated by 0's). The followup question is "Can we introduce a digit of 1 in base 3 using $a(x)$"?
- We could do that with $ a(20) = 200 = 21102_3$, and so I thought that the set of achievable numbers were Numbers in base 3 whose starting digit was 2.
- Looking at $a^2 (20) = 20000 = 1000102202_3$, I realized that would give us $1$ (and $10_3, 100_3, \ldots)$.
- With that realization, we simply want the inequality in the claim.
- Of course, there could be other ways of reaching $n$. One possible approach could be to show that we can reach all even numbers, and then by applying $b(x)$ we can reach all numbers.

Comment: I think your claim of denseness mod $\log 3$ is not so clear.  It's equivalent to saying that $\frac{2^L}{\log 3}$ is dense mod 1, which is equivalent to saying that $\frac{1}{\log 3}$ contains all possible finite binary strings--a weak version of being normal in base 2.  I assume this is true but unknown.

Comment: @RaviFernando Normal in base 2 is too strong (and I'm unsure if it's true). The original version can be proved by Pigeonhole principle (and is a standard olympiad problem). Let me add the solution.

Comment: I think you're confusing multiplication with addition.  The standard pigeonhole argument will show that $\mathbb N$ is dense in $\mathbb R/(\alpha \mathbb Z)$ (where $\alpha$ is irrational), or that $\{2^n\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R^{>0}/\alpha^{\mathbb Z}$ (where $\alpha$ isn't a rational power of $2$).  What you need is that $\{2^n\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R/(\mathbb Z \cdot \log 3)$.  This is really nontrivial, in light of my first comment.

Comment: In particular your third spoiler box is incorrect:  having $2^a$ and $2^b$ close to each other modulo an *additive* $B$ tells you nothing about the value of $2^{a-b}$ modulo $B$.

Comment: @RaviFernando Ah yes, I stand corrected (and in fact [I previously showed that there exists a number where this isn't dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608727/prove-that-2n-alpha-2n-alpha-is-dense-in-0-1?rq=1).) Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Oh, nice.  I guess in the worst case scenario, you could leave the answer up as a conditional proof.  I would love to see an unconditional version, though, since it's a clever idea and much more conceptual than the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment, but with the help of a computer, I found that all numbers in $\{1,\dots,7000\}$ are indeed reachable. I verified this with the following Python code, which uses a priority queue to find reachable numbers. The best priority ordering I found was to try the $\lfloor x/3\rfloor$ operation first, then to try the $\lceil x^2/2\rceil$ operation, and resorting to $9x+2$ last.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBBbsIwELz7FXvDBjdxwgEVlUp9Qs4RQgY2JFJip46hQlXfnnqJUYXonmzP7Mx4@quvrVmOY@VsBzXq/hOarrfO3y79eajldLI9Y167E/oBNjCg506bE/JMwkqpTAhmzt0uMnYtVj7QAqIYGxBN3CnVVrAiXEqupBJbxr7qpkV42n0HtWYQ5nB2Dg2JxRi8EGW2vWHe7vTxGNUiMU2XQkKIxePDfJ7DAjKRpjkBuXyd3zUXkItJqbIOeO8a6xp/DQku2EoKJaAx0WaKQ9NUBIGxnlD63R9GQy9J2OAk8IDcO@WF/N/ukR6N3qYi1/AA3gqYKkscdvaCz340T9W@bCBjLLgbz2cfbUuMPbqBPvOdySRJJNn9gHYIDvWh1vsWk5kYx18)

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

targets = set(range(1, 7001))
num_targets_left = 7000

seen = set([0])
Q = [(0,0)]

while num_targets_left > 0:
    current = heappop(Q)[1]
    to_add = [(0,current//3), (1,(current**2 + 1)//2), (2,9*current + 2)]
    for (priority_level, num) in to_add:
        if num not in seen:
            seen.add(num)
            heappush(Q, (priority_level, num))
            if num <= 7000: 
                targets.remove(num)
                num_targets_left -= 1

print('All numbers in {1,...,7000} are reachable.')
```

I found the the hardest number was $6121$. The path that led to it below. Here, `third x 7` means you do this $\lfloor x/3\rfloor$ operation $7$ times.

```
Number          Next operation(s)
----------------------------------
0               9x + 2
2               9x + 2
20              half-square
200             third x 3
7               half-square
25              third x 1
8               half-square
32              third x 1
10              half-square
50              third x 1
16              half-square
128             third x 2
14              half-square
98              half-square
4802            third x 5
19              half-square
181             half-square
16381           third x 4
202             half-square
20402           third x 4
251             half-square
31501           third x 4
388             half-square
75272           third x 6
103             half-square
5305            third x 3
196             half-square
19208           third x 2
2134            half-square
2276978         third x 5
9370            half-square
43898450        third x 9
2230            half-square
2486450         third x 6
3410            half-square
5814050         third x 6
7975            half-square
31800313        third x 7
14540           half-square
105705800       third x 8
16111           half-square
129782161       third x 9
6593            half-square
21733825        third x 7
9937            half-square
49371985        third x 8
7525            half-square
28312813        third x 8
4315            half-square
9309613         third x 6
12770           half-square
81536450        third x 8
12427           half-square
77215165        third x 8
11768           half-square
69242912        third x 8
10553           half-square
55682905        third x 7
25460           half-square
324105800       third x 9
16466           half-square
135564578       third x 8
20662           half-square
213459122       third x 8
32534           half-square
529230578       third x 9
26887           half-square
361455385       third x 10
6121
```

Comment: As it is an Olympiad problem, can this be proved without using computer?

Comment: +1 , nice try it online thing, I don't really like bloated stuff like that, but it's also dope at the same time. :)

Comment: Can it be done in reverse?